# How can I change the text when its length 14 characters with TextInputFormat?

Tags: flutter, dart

well, I have a textFormField. This TextFormField will use to take user phone number. What I wanna thing is when the phone number length is 14 characters, all texts which on seems on the TextFormField would "xxx xxx".

How can I doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`mask_text_input_formatter`](https://import%20%27package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart%27;)

```dart
TextFormField(
inputFormatters: [
 ExampleMask(
      formatter: MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: "+# (###) ###-##-##"),
      textInputType: TextInputType.phone
    ),
],
```

Comment: Many thanks, I have missed that package,